Al acceder por URL a mi página web, no me funciona si pongo "www" al principio
Me he creado una página web, y le he puesto algo de contenido. He esperado 5 días y mi página web está perfecta (el primer día ya lo estaba también). El caso es que si en la url pongo euricky999.000webhostapp.com me sale mi página, pero si pongo www.euricky999.000webhostapp.com dice que no se ha encontrado la página web. ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?
Contenido de mi .htaccess:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 weeks"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress



# HTID:23163121: DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES 
BELOW
allow from 127.0.0.1
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE 
HTID:23163121:

# HTID:23426253: DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES 
BELOW
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)? 
(euricky999.000webhostapp.com)(/)?.*$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*.(.*)$ https://srv-access.w3spaces.com [R,NC]
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE 
HTID:23426253:


Pues no se, ambas direcciones apunta a la misma IP, pero quizás el virtualhost que te han creado los de 000webhostapp.com no contempla el www apuntando a la misma carpeta que el otro, o bien el .htaccess que tienes hace algo al respecto (lo dudo)

Y lo sabrias arreglar o no (el .htaccess)?

Te recomiendo echarle un vistazo a github pages, es mejor que los host gratis que encontraras por ahi.

@JefferzonBol gracias, lo acabo de mirar y tiene buena pinta... Daré de baja la web esta y me registró ahí. Tienes usuario de github?

¿Es una pregunta trampa?  A ver, a ciegas imposible.  Si pones el contenido de tu .htaccess en la pregunta quizás vea algo que esté forzando ese 404 y te lo pueda indicar.

@masterguru hecho, ya la he editado

En principio le sobra todo lo que viene debajo del # END WordPress porque nunca llegará a ejecutarlo, pues la rule anterior no se lo permite.  Pero aparte de eso, no veo yo nada que impida que se muestre tambien el www en tu dominio en el .htaccess, por lo tanto el problema lo tienes en el panel de control de ese hosting, no en el htaccess, que seguramente en alguna parte le puede decir que tambien quieres que el www apunte a esa carpeta (dicho de otro modo, tu virtualhost no parece contemplar el subdominio www)

Es un problema de redirección. Las paginas con www son diferentes a las que no lo tienen, por lo que se suele hacer es comprar ese dominio y ponerle a esa redirección (redirección 301), para que esta mande al usuario a la pagina que si tiene el contenido.

En el gestor de dominios (Editor de Zonas), coloca un registro tipo CNAME desde www.tupagina.com -> tupagina.com

@aeportugal Dudo que eso solucione nada. El CNAME lo unico que hará será acabar resolviendo el dominio con www a la misma IP que el dominio sin www, que por cierto, ya está sucediendo ahora, así que no notará ningún cambio. El problema lo tiene en el virtualhost de su servidor web, el cual carece del subdominio www, y que seguramente solo puede gestionar con el panel que tenga acceso, pues también dudo que le permitan editarlo a pelo y reinciar su servidor web.  Esto es una pregunta para "soporte" de ese hosting gratuito, que imagino que será ninguno.

Tené en cuenta que a partir del 14 de octubre 000webhost va a dejar de funcionar. Deberías empezar a mudar tu sitio a otro hosting.

No se yo si comprar un dominio tiene nada que ver con poner una redirección 301 en .htaccess o dentro de un PHP con la función header().  Comprar el dominio solo te permite decir cuales son sus nameservers, y no hay registros DNS "reales" donde poner redirecciones 301 (hay algunos registradores que te lo permiten, pero porque usan otros servicios para ello, no son registros DNS reales). Además, el OP pregunta por ese hosting gratuito específico, dudo que quiera comprarlo.  Tu respuesta no parece acertada, la verdad, debería ser un comentario, lo siento.

@Mady si, lo he visto. Estoy pensando en alternativas, como la que dijo JefferzonBol, github pages...

@masterguru el Wordpress ya lo desinstalé de mi página web, pero manualmente, porque el desinstalador automático no funcionaba... No lo quise quitar por si acaso y porque no sabia que quitar...
